# How to best upload high volume of resources through filepond?

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, plugins, jszip, filepond

I've recently been using [filepond](https://github.com/pqina/filepond) for an enterprise web application that allows end-users to upload a maximum of 1,500 images (medium size, avg 200Kb, max 500Kb).

There is a very low degree of backend processing once an image is uploaded other than its temporary storage in a database. We later perform asynchronous processing picking up the files from that temporary storage. But the current challenge we are seeing is that the browser serialization is extending the upload up to 2 hours! We've been able to decrease this time close to 1 hour by increasing the max parallel uploads in filepond already, but this is still far from acceptable (the target is 20min), and we still see the serialization occurring in Chrome Dev Tools with such a volume of images being uploaded.

With this in mind, I'm currently looking for a new filepond plugin to zip the dropped files and then upload a single archive to the backend, without the user bothering to do that himself. I couldn't find anything related at [filepond's plugins page](https://pqina.nl/filepond/plugins.html) and most listed there seem to be related to image transformation. Hopefully the [jszip library](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) could do the trick. Am I on the right track? Any further suggestions?

Other things in the radar our team is exploring:

- creating multiple DNS endpoints to increase the number of parallel requests by the browser;
- researching CDN services alternatives;

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with 'serialization' are you encoding the images as base64 before upload?

Comment: Believe filepond library is already doing that, yes. By serialization I mean the browser is sending requests almost one by one due to the amount of files. There is, I believe, a max no of parallel requests allowed in the browsers hence the issue.